# How do I enable my javascript code using a button made in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I want to create a button in HTML that when clicked on, brings up the javascript code (prompts). How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Chek this out**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSEyM/)

It will work!

**HTML:**

```
 <input id="button" type="button" value="Klick me"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    confirm("Great to see you," + " " + prompt("What's Your Name"));
};
```

Comment: dont forget to click the chekmark :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="button1" type="button" value="click me" onclick="clickme()"/>
<p id="value"></p>

<script type="javascript">

function clickme()
{
   var s = prompt("write a number");
   if(s!=null)
   document.getElementById("value").innerHTML= s;
}

</script>
```

put the value of the prompt in  paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this carefully

```
<form name="my_form" id="form_id" method="post" action="my_page_url">
    <!--  rest part of your form fields go here -->
    <!-- this is the submit button -->
    <input type="submit" name="my_button" value="but_value" onclick="myfunction()"/>
</form>
```

You can submit this form as like this. Please note there are many other ways to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction()
    {
         document.getElementById('form_id').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Please go through some tutorials. There are lot of tutorials for this. Make a google search. Good luck

Comment: Please don't recommend using in-line (obtrusive) JavaScript event-handling (it really is bad practice, and makes maintenance harder than it needs to be).

Comment: @DavidThomas : i have shown this code since, just inform him that there is also in-line java script event-handling in js :). thanks for this comment